# jQuery Hide/Show Within If/Else Statement Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a quick jQuery slideshow and I'm having some issues. I have a variable that increases or decreases when you press the navigation buttons, and the code is supposed to show or hide the images based on the number. It doesn't appear to work however, only showing img1 and not displaying any of the other images. I have verified that the currentImage variable is changing properly. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImage = 0;
    $("#next").click(function(){
        currentImage++;
        if(currentImage > 2)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
        currentImage--;
        if(currentImage < 0)
        {
            currentImage = 2;
        }
    });
    if(currentImage == 0)
    {
        $(".img1").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img1").hide();
    }
    if(currentImage == 1)
    {
        $(".img2").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img2").hide();
    }
    if(currentImage == 2)
    {
        $(".img3").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img3").hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Uhm, the entire logic that shows and hides the images are ***OUTSIDE*** the event handlers, so nothing really happens when you click any of those buttons, other than the variable changing ?

Comment: just include the if else logic inside both events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only run the If/Then/Else statements once, on document load, you need to rerun them after the click events:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImage = 0;
    $("#next").click(function(){
        currentImage++;
        if(currentImage > 2)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        refreshImg();
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
        currentImage--;
        if(currentImage < 0)
        {
            currentImage = 2;
        }
        refreshImg();
    });
    function refreshImg(){
        if(currentImage == 0)
        {
            $(".img1").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img1").hide();
        }
        if(currentImage == 1)
        {
            $(".img2").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img2").hide();
        }
        if(currentImage == 2)
        {
            $(".img3").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img3").hide();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Craig you guys are fast

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

The code showing or hiding the images should be executed when the button is clicked. At the moment it is only hiding or showing the button on document ready.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var currentImage = 0;
        $("#next").click(function(){
            currentImage++;
            if(currentImage > 2)
            {
                currentImage = 0;
            }
            ShowOrHideImage();
        });
        $("#previous").click(function(){
            currentImage--;
            if(currentImage < 0)
            {
                currentImage = 2;
            }
            ShowOrHideImage();
        });

    function ShowOrHideImage() {
        if(currentImage == 0)
        {
            $(".img1").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img1").hide();
        }
        if(currentImage == 1)
        {
            $(".img2").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img2").hide();
        }
        if(currentImage == 2)
        {
            $(".img3").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".img3").hide();
        }
    }   
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statements are running as soon as the document is ready, at that time the value of `currentImage` is 0. You can stick it into a function and call it every time there's a click

```
var toggleImages = function(current) {

  if(current== 0)
    {
        $(".img1").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img1").hide();
    }
    if(current== 1)
    {
        $(".img2").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img2").hide();
    }
    if(current== 2)
    {
        $(".img3").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img3").hide();
    }
};


$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImage = 0;
    $("#next").click(function(){
        currentImage++;
        if(currentImage > 2)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
        toggleImages(currentImage);
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
        currentImage--;
        if(currentImage < 0)
        {
            currentImage = 2;
        }
        toggleImages(currentImage);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     currentImage = 0;
      updateImgae(currentImage);
    $("#next").click(function(){
        currentImage++;
        if(currentImage > 2)
        {
            currentImage = 0;
        }
         updateImgae(currentImage);
    });
    $("#previous").click(function(){
        currentImage--;
        if(currentImage < 0)
        {
            currentImage = 2;
        }
         updateImgae(currentImage);
    });
    function updateImgae(currentImage){
    if(currentImage == 0)
    {
        $(".img1").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img1").hide();
    }
    if(currentImage == 1)
    {
        $(".img2").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img2").hide();
    }
    if(currentImage == 2)
    {
        $(".img3").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".img3").hide();
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

a much simpler version - get the source of the image, increment it or decrement it and replace the image with the new source. requires the images to be named 1.jpg,  2.jpg and 3.jpg etc (and placed within the correct folder - I have used images/slideshow/1.jpg etc).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                       
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" value = "-1">Previous Image</button>
        <img id="slideshowImage" src="images/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="Image 1" height="100" width="100"/>
        <button type="button" value = "+1">Next Image</button>

<script>
    $(":button").click(function() {
        var imageSrc=$('#slideshowImage').attr('src').split('/');
            var count = parseFloat(imageSrc[2]);
            var newSrc = count+parseFloat(($(this).val()))
                if(newSrc>3){newSrc=1}else{if(newSrc==0){newSrc=3}};
        $('#slideshowImage').attr('src','images/slideshow/'+newSrc+'.jpg').attr('alt','Image '+newSrc)
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially on the click of either button, a function is called that determines the image source, splits it to get the specific image number, increments or decrements that number based on the button pressed, and sets the new image srouce and alt attributes to the new count. The benefit of this approach apart from the small amount of code, is that it is easy to scale and add more pictures to the slideshow in the future. Hope this helps, gavgrif